# library to locate -lsocket

Tags: linux, sockets

I am running client.c code in linux pangolin 12.04, happycoders-libsocket is installed
but still got error that says:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsocket
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
May I know what can be done to resolve this please?

Comment: You're building C code against a C++ library?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Nope I'm not..

Comment: "client.c" implies C and Happycoders libsocket is a C++ library, so yes, you are.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: there are no C++ libraries, there are C++ symbols in libraries.

Comment: @n.m.: Fair enough. But the issue that the asker doesn't want to perform what they *think* they want to perform still stands.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: wrong. If C code compiles against its headers, it should link too.

Comment: I mean, a C++ library could theoretically provide C-compatible headers *without* `extern "C"` but that would be rather odd. In any case, this should never cause a library to be missed by the linker.

Comment: Now let me guess. You are building a 32 bit program on a 64 bit machine, right?

Comment: OK libsockets is a purely C++ library. You probably are not compiling against it, and should not try to link it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have C code that uses BSD sockets on Linux then you do not need to link against additional libraries; GLibC provides the socket functions through `libc`.